# onInterceptTouchEvent in a table cell behavior

Tags: android

I'm trying to catch the ACTION_UP and ACTION_CANCEL on my RecyclerView, but I want every other event to be caught by it's children, but it seems the child that caught the first event is the only one that catches all the following ones. Here my code for the intercept event.

```java
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    boolean takeEventControl = false;
    switch (e.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            takeEventControl = true;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            // Some processing
            takeEventControl = false;
            break;
    }
    return takeEventControl;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    // Some code
}
```

And here is my code for the child views

```java
@Override
public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent event) {
    switch (e.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            //Some processing
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            //Some processing
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I already tested it and find that if I return true the first time the onInterceptTouchEvent is triggered the onTouchEvent is called successfully, but in my code I need to call the child onTouch when the event action is ACTION_DOWN or ACTION_MOVE, and the onTouchEvent on ACTION_UP or ACTION_CANCEL but the last one is never called, I hope someone could explain me what's happening here.

Comment: Try overriding dispatchTouchEvent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid having a view control touches after the `ACTION_DOWN`, have all views return `false` in their `onTouch` for `ACTION_DOWN`. You can then return `true` for other touch events that are truly being handled.

The reason behind this is the first view to return `true` for `ACTION_DOWN` will be the only view to receive future `onTouch` calls until after an `ACTION_UP` or `ACTION_CANCEL` is received.

Comment: Yes, it seems this was actually the problem, but even returning false on every view the `onTouch` is never called for `ACTION_UP` or `ACTION_CANCEL` unless the view where I wanted to do the handling returned true for the `ACTION_DOWN` event so I triggered everything on the `onInterceptTouchEvent `. Thanks for your answer.